# Add specification from a loop

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa

In a spring boot 3 application I try to use specification

```
public Page<User> advancedSearch(UserSearch search, Pageable page) {

      String[] splittedValues = search.name.split(" ");
    

      Specification<User> hasPersonWithName = (Root<User> root, CriteriaQuery<?> cq, CriteriaBuilder cb) -> {

            ...

            return pre;
        };

    return findAll(specification, page);

}
```

I need for every value in splittedValues to add a global specification

```
for (String splittedName: splittedValues) {
   specification.or(splittedName);
}
```

and pass it to findAll

I don't understand how to do it

Edit

you solution seem to work but

that generate

```
where
    1=1 
    or like e1_0.name "%bob%"
    or like e1_0.name "%jame%"
```

It's there a way to get

```
where
    1=1 
    and (
    like e1_0.name "%bob%"
    or like e1_0.name "%jame%"
    )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `or` operator , you combine multiple conditions, checking whether the `name` of `User` contains one of the `splittedValues`. Predicate is then returned from specification.

I hope that was what you wanted, in case I didn't understand, please correct me. Here is an example if so, adapt to your own code.

Edit: To get  `1=1 and (like e1_0.name "%bob%" or like e1_0.name "%jame%")`, you can use `cb.or` method to combine the conditions, resulting `nameConditions` is then combined with `pre` using `cb.and`.

```
public Page<User> advancedSearch(UserSearch search, Pageable page) {
    String[] splittedValues = search.name.split(" ");

    Specification<User> hasPersonWithName = (Root<User> root, CriteriaQuery<?> cq, CriteriaBuilder cb) -> {
        Predicate pre = cb.conjunction();
        Predicate nameConditions = null;
        for (String splittedName: splittedValues) {
            if (nameConditions == null) {
                nameConditions = cb.like(root.get("name"), "%" + splittedName + "%");
            } else {
                nameConditions = cb.or(nameConditions, cb.like(root.get("name"), "%" + splittedName + "%"));
            }
        }
        if (nameConditions != null) {
            pre = cb.and(pre, nameConditions);
        }
        return pre;
    };
```

return findAll(hasPersonWithName, page);
}

Comment: yes I done an edit but clarify

Comment: I edited the code above with your required result of  `1=1 and (like e1_0.name "%bob%" or like e1_0.name "%jame%")`

Comment: it's there a reason the framework add 1=1?

Comment: It's mainly there as a "dummy" condition that is always true, to allow easy build of complex conditions using `cb.and` and `cb.or`, while not having to worry about handling case where there's no conditions. Of course, OP should feel free to optimize as needed, this is merely an idea of how to achieve what he/she wants.